# How do I fix the error that occurs when I put these else statements in my function?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, syntax, syntax-error

I'm attempting to create a wepbage where when the user clicks a button, they receive a compliment. I'm doing this using `button.addEventListener("click", generator);`. However, I kept getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else` when I checked the console. I suspected it was an issue with the if/else syntax, and I removed the semicolons I accidentally put after each block in order to see if that was the issue. That switched it from `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else` to `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`. I've looked over it a number of times to try and find a mistake but I just can't find the problem.

Here's the function:

```
var generator = function(){
        var complimentNum = round(random(1,5));
        if(complimentNum == 1){
            compliment.textContent = "You have a great smile!";
        }
        else if(complimentNum == 2){
            compliment.textContent = "You are so kind to others!";
        }
        else if(complimentNum == 3){
            compliment.textContent = "Your laugh is beautiful!";
        }
        else if(complimentNum == 4){
            compliment.textContent = "Your eyes are beautiful!";
        }
        else(complimentNum == 5){
            compliment.textContent = "You have good taste.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `else(complimentNum == 5)` should be `else if(complimentNum == 5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code to make it work fine and also change the random method.

[You should know the difference between if, else if and else.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

```js
compliment = document.getElementById('compliment');
var generator = function(){
    // modified the generation of random number
    var complimentNum = Math.round(Math.random()*4+1);
    if(complimentNum == 1){
        compliment.textContent = "You have a great smile!";
    }
    else if(complimentNum == 2){
        compliment.textContent = "You are so kind to others!";
    }
    else if(complimentNum == 3){
        compliment.textContent = "Your laugh is beautiful!";
    }
    else if(complimentNum == 4){
        compliment.textContent = "Your eyes are beautiful!";
    }
    // change to else if
    else if(complimentNum == 5){
        compliment.textContent = "You have good taste.";
    }
    // how to use else
    else {
        compliment.textContent = "You have good taste.";
    }
}
```

```html
<span id="compliment"></span>
<br/>
<button onclick="generator()">click</button>
```